# Memory Leak when calling Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak somewhere in my program, and using some tools I think this is the location in my code.  So, is there something wrong with this function and how the stored procedure is called?

`CustomSQLConn` is given to the class when it is created.

```
private void flagDeleted(ABCDocument mydoc){
    try {           

        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        try{
            CallableStatement cs1;
            cs1 = CustomSQLConn.prepareCall("{ call flagFolderDeleted(?) }");
            cs1.setInt(1, mydoc.getId());
            cs1.execute();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Got an exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(rs1 != null) rs1.close();
            rs1 = null;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Got an exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // END flagDeleted
```

The connection is not being closed here either, since the class uses it for other processes.

Comment: What brought you to the conclusion that you have a memory leak, and what brought you to the conclusion this code is responsible for it? I don't see anything problematic here.

Comment: I'm using "Yourkit Java Profiler" to look at the process.  The class that has this function keeps getting called without closing.  Also, only when this function is called, my memory is raised, and doesn't go back down.   I took out this class for a while, and the memory didnt go up.

Comment: still don't see how that could indicate a memory leak. What do you mean "getting called without closing"? The class has a close method that doesn't get called? You just need to call it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are closing the `ResultSet` but not closing the `CallableStatement`.

Comment: I'm closing it and letting you know after running it for a while.  Also, now that you mention it, I'm not using the `ResultSet`, so I removed it completely. (That's what happens when you copy/paste).